# Good programming, should i reuse values?

Tags: javascript

I have been practicing JavaScript for the last 6 months and am currently trying to improve the way i code.

What i would like to know is.. Should i assign a value i'm gonna keep using to a variable even tho it's not related to what i'm trying to accomplish?

In this example, i keep reusing init_value because it's equal to 3.

```
        function roll_dice(){
         return Math.floor(Math.random() * init_value);
        }

       var source = ["hello.jpg","hello2.jpg","hello3.jpg", "hello4.jpg"];
       var init_value = 3;

       if( (source.length - 1) === init_value ){
         var roll = roll_dice();
         alert(roll);
       }

       for(i = init_value; i >= 0; i--){
        alert(source[i]);
       }
```

Comment: What does `init_value` mean? Is it just `source.length - 1`?

Comment: Basically, it's not supposed to mean anything anyway, it's just something random i came up with to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. Give your variables meaningful names and use them for what they are designed. There is no reason whatsoever to consider re-using variables, unless you are developing on limited hardware (for example embedded systems).

An example (just some mock-code in the same spirit as your code):

```
 var max_users = 10;
 var max_connections = 10;

 if (connections == max_connections) {
      alert("No more connections allowed!");
 }

 if (users == max_users) {
      alert("Maximum number of users reached.");
 }
```

Even though the numbers are the same, I will not re-use the same variable. I also will not create a variable like `i` or `max_connections_or_users` in this case, unless that is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what it would look like if you chose variables for just their value:

```
    var superman = 1,
    marypoppins = 0,
    mario = 3;

    function roll_dice(){
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * superman * mario );
    }

   var source = ["hello.jpg","hello2.jpg","hello3.jpg", "hello4.jpg"];
   var init_value = mario + superman * marypoppins;

   if( (source.length - superman) === mario + marypoppins ){
     var roll = roll_dice();
     alert(roll);
   }

   for(i = init_value; i >= marypoppins * mario; i--){
    alert(source[i]);
   }
```

Still think reusing variables is cool?